# Restoring my Site collection from my development machine to my staging machine will show blank page

Tags: deployment, installation, restore

I have a team site collection inside my development machine; containing Apps, text, pictures, etc.

So i back up the site collection from my development machine, i create a new web application inside my staging machine , then i restore the site collection to my staging machine. the result was that the team site will display a blank page with no text, images , apps, etc inside it. so can anyone adive on this ? baring in mind that the database name, server name are different in ym development machine and on my staging machine.

Comment: How are you backing up and restoring the site collection?

Comment: Are you restoring a cmp file? via powershell?

Comment: yes i am restoring my site collection using the folloiwng command Restore-spsite -identity http://staging01:48514/sites/Intranet/ -path C:\Users\myusername\Desktop\intranet.  where intranet file was generated from backup the site collection on my development machine.